# Remove Expired Scratch Orgs From VSCode

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

Now that DX has been around for a minute and it's almost 2 years since [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/181780/removing-old-hub-org-or-non-scratch-org-from-salesforce-dx-org-list) was posed from a CLI perspective, I thought it would be worth asking. Is there yet a convenient way to remove expired scratch orgs from my list within VS Code?

[image]

Currently when I click on the current default org *(above)*, I get the following list *(below)*. These are all outdated, I wish they would auto remove themselves, but since they apparently don't, what is the best way to manage them?
[image]

Comment: If you want a more gui-oriented solution, you could create a VS Code extension that executes that command in Javascript that is accessible through the VS Code command palette, or extend the default cli with a dx extension. Either is feasible

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There's no GUI for it, but you can go to the terminal and type in the following command:

```
sfdx force:org:list --clean
```

This will clear up all expired scratch orgs.

Comment: Do the above command delete all orgs including active too?

Comment: @RKCY No, it will only delete orgs with INVALID_GRANT (either the org was deleted or the session is no longer valid).

Answer (score 1):

Even though

> sfdx force:org:list --clean

still works, it has been deprecated and **you should instead use**

> [sf org list --clean](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_org_commands_unified.htm#cli_reference_org_list_unified)

You can read more about it [in this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2022/12/big-improvements-coming-to-the-salesforce-cli)